# Average speed / Velocity

Tags: kinematics, velocity, speed, relative-motion

We know that in kinematics we have the concepts about "average speed". By definition the average speed is the total of the distance divided by time, but I still don't get it what is the average speed intuitively and why average speed is so important, and in my opinion average speed it doesn't seems accurate, for example if you say the average 12 km/h , it doesn't mean that you constantly drive with 12 km/h. I am still confuse what average speed is actually mean and why do we need to learn it?

Answer (score 0):

> ...for example if you say the average 12 km/h , it doesn't mean that you constantly drive with 12 km/h.

Many measurements in real life imply averaging - at least because of the limited precision with which we can measure distance and time. **The speed that a car speedometer shows is an average over a small distance and small time.** Although the fluctuations about average are usually rather small, it is fair to say that the speed of a car is not always constant, even when the arrow/number on the speedometer doesn't move.

In older cars one could actually see that it takes time for the speedometer to settle to a particular number after a period of acceleration or even see its arrow shaking when driving. In most modern cars the averaging time is much shorter - at least shorter than a human reaction time (about a quarter of a second), so that the fluctuations of speed are not perceptible - all we observe is a speed average over our reaction time. (In addition, the fluctuations are small, if using cruise control.)

Finally, in a different context the speed shown by a speedometer may be considered as instantaneous: e.g., if we are talking about speed variation during a long trip (e.g., from New York to Denver), and we are not trying to be more precise than, say $0.1$km/h. In this case average speed can be still a meaningful parameter - e.g., when calculating how much time it will take you to get from Denver to Los Angeles or how much gas your car spends per kilometer/mile.

**Remark:** a textbook matter, but worth reminding - the average speed and average velocity are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Average speed is an important concept. Say the motion is non uniform at such times if we need to approximate the velocity then we use the concept of average velocity. If suppose you travel the same distance in same time t as you have covered the distance with non uniform speed you could have covered the motion with a speed v at every instant, which is the average velocity.

However instantaneous velocity has its own benefits than average velocity, still we use this concept for approximation purposes

Suppose we don't know anything about instantaneous speed/ velocity we could approximate the journey with average speed, Now again average velocity can only be used if we are focusing on displacement. Average velocity doesn't care about stoping or speeding.

Now suppose someone asks you how much time does it take to go from your home to school
if your school is $8000m$  away and your $\text{Average velocity}$ is 60m/s you will tell the time to be $8000/60$ which is $133$ seconds at such cases Average velocity comes to our help.

Even the speedometer shows the average speed for a small distance is a small interval of time